# Docker - Local Development on container

Tags: docker

Getting started with Docker and I wanted to know the following:

I want to develop a Laravel application, all of the files are located on my local machine. However, I cannot seem to figure out how I am able to synchronise the files on my local machine to the server itself?

This was available using vagrant so I'm just wondering is there an effective and easy solution to this problem?

Comment: You can mount host directories on the container. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth I believe so. So my project (on local) is located at ~/Sites/mysite which on the server should be: /var/www/mysite -- When I make a change to "mysite" on the local, it should automatically update on my main docker image -- Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/
Probably you have to do something like:

```
$ docker run -d --name mycontainer -v /home/user/Sites/mysite:/var/www/mysite my/image
```

This way you mount the host folder to you container folder. This means that the folder on your host will be visible from your container. These two folders are the same folder physically!

Comment: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH. Getting this error @Balázs Mária Németh

Comment: Hello, Just read the tutorial and familiarize a little with docker. The error you mentioned is just a syntax problem in the command you issued. The example Balázs made should not be taken as literal.